# How do you find $x$ from $y=\operatorname{sinc}(x)$?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have an equation:

$$\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 0.5$$

How do I find $x$ from this?

I realise there's probably not a simple equation to describe the inverse, but is there a numerical method I can use to solve this?

Comment: Fixed point iteration $x = 2 \sin x$ is one approach and it yields http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+2+sin+x

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm Try Newton's method.

Comment: @clairharrison: Newton's Method and others also work and see the same result as the Fixed Point above: See: [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=newton%27s+method%2C+2%2Asin%28x%29+-+x%2C+x0+%3D2). It converges in 4-steps for a start value of 2.

Comment: you can draw functions sin(x) and 0.5x and you can estimate its root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cannot find a closed form for this, so you are right, numerical methods are needed.

We can use any root finding approach.

For Fixed Point Iteration, we have:

$$x = 2 \sin x$$

This leads to this root found using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+2+sin+x)

We can also use Newton's Method with (converges in 4-steps for a start value of 2. ):

$$f(x) = 2 \sin x - x$$

Here are the same results using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=newton%27s+method%2C+2%2Asin%28x%29+-+x%2C+x0+%3D2).

The root is:

$$x = \pm ~1.895494267033981\ldots$$